# Django форма администратора

Tags: python, django

Когда сервер джанго запущен, ввожу в поисковую строку /admin и мне не выдает форму входа для администратора, суперпользовтаеля я создал в cmd, как исправить эту проблему?
Во всех обучениях для регистрации суперпользователя вводится в поисковую строку /admin и они могут управлять сайтом как админтстраторы, а у меня нет формы для авторизации суперпользователя

Comment: какие ошибки?..

Comment: Просто нет формы для ввода моего логина и пароля, пишет нет такого пути

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если вам пишет нет такого пути, проверьте есть ли в файле urls в рут папке наличие /admin